# Network Discovery is Turned Off, But still visible from other computer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, network-shares

I'm connected to the Wifi here in our office so my laptop is visible on the network of the other computers and I wanted to be hidden that is why I turned-off all the stuffs in the advanced sharing settings like the Network Discovery, file sharing and etc. but they can still see me.

I have already tried typing Network config server /hidden:yes and ipconfig/flushdns on CMD and it didnt work for me.

I'm sorry for my bad english so I hope you guys understand it. Thank you!

Comment: What kind of visibility do you mean? Listed in the network discovery window? Reachable via TCP/IP? etc.

Comment: Visible in the network discovery window

Comment: "I'm connected to the Wifi here in our office" ... "I wanted to be hidden" - be aware that your employer might not like that. perhaps ask first if it is permitted? If so, maybe your IT department can help?

Comment: I found two services you could try to disable. Press “WIN+R” and type services.msc in RUN window. Disable “Function Discovery Resource Publication” and “Server” service. They are about network discovery.

Comment: @Mawg My company is too small so we don't have IT department and I'm the only IT here. I'm only a college student trainee in here and I've already said to them the things that Im going to do and yes I was permitted.

Comment: @daidai IT WORKS! I stop the “Function Discovery Resource Publication” from running then tadaahh! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Ok, so long as you asked your boss first - don't ever take the risk of being fired for something that seems trivial to you :-)  @daidai If you post a answer then Mhtyr can accept it and that will help others in future.